# Extended methods not showing in view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Created extended methods as shown below:

```
public static class RBAC_ExtendedMethods
    {

        public static bool IsSysAdmin(this ControllerBase controller)
        {
            bool IsSysAdmin = false;
            try
            {
                //Check if the requesting user has the System Administrator privilege...
                IsSysAdmin = new RBACUser(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name).IsSysAdmin;
            }
            catch { }
            return IsSysAdmin;
        }
    }
```

Able to use this method in controller action method:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (this.IsSysAdmin())
            {

            }
        }
```

but while using in view can't see it using ViewContext :

```
@{
    if(ViewContext.Controller.)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell your using the extension methods correctly and they should be avaialbe in the `Razor` view however what we cant see is if you are including the extension method in the `View` itself.

There are multiple ways of including the Controller Extension method. The extension method namespace must be either part of the `using` statements for the view such as below.

*Note as you didnt provide the namespace I will use `MyCoolNamespace.ExtensionMethods` as the namespace for your extension method*

**Razor View**

Add a using statement in the view itself.

```
@using MyCoolNamespace.ExtensionMethods
```

**Web.config**

Inside the `web.config` located in `~/Views/web.config` add the namespace in the `system.web.webPages.razor/pages/namespaces` section such as.

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <!-- ommited -->
        <add namespace="MyCoolNamespace.ExtensionMethods" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Either of these two ways will enable the extension method in your views. The later option enables it for all views that inherit from the `web.config` path.

```
@{
    if (ViewContext.Controller.IsSysAdmin())
    {
            //do something cool for sys admins
    }
}
```